# How to force VSCode to use default PostCSS syntax <style> tag?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, postcss

I cant set vscode to mark  tags in vue component as postcss syntax.

Is totally not a solition here as I figured it to work assets stopped loading by default but I dont want to struggle with webpacker for it. 




I want force  tag as postcss from vscode side. 


How can I do it?